# How to have JS from HTML call a function INSIDE a node.js script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently using Node.JS to back end into different systems. From my web page I want to be able to call a function in the Node.JS script and have it return some values.

Here is a diagram of what I mean.

JS --> calls function --> node.js --> executes function called by normal js

Comment: And what about AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS on your browser lives in the client machine. The JS on your Node.js lives in the server machine. There's this great divide between them called The Internet, so you technically cannot *"have JS from HTML **call** a function INSIDE a node.js script"*.

What you do instead is make a network request from your browser JS over The Internet to your server JS and have it respond. There's many ways to do this, most common of which is [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: _called The Internet_ :-)

Comment: @baao I could have called the server machine "The Cloud" to make it sound more magical. :D

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought I was missing something.